# How do I output the min and max values in jQRangeSlider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui

I am using the jQRangeSlider plugin to create a date range slider. I'm trying to output the max and min values using this function:

```
var dateSliderMax = $("#slider").dateRangeSlider("max");
console.log(dateSliderMax.toString());
```

The following string is returned:

> Fri Feb 11 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

I want to output the date to the console in the format of `20110211` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j1qy9sj/). How can I achieve this?

Comment: "20110211" is not a reasonable way to define a date format, do you mean YYYYMMDD? What is the value of *dateSliderMax*? Is it a Date object, string, …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the date into a JavaScript date, and then output it in YYYYMMDD format.

```
var date = new Date(dateSliderMax);
alert((date.getFullYear().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1)) + date.getDate());
```

To get the month and day to always be in two digit format, you start with a "0", and keep it only if the month/day is less than two digits.

```
"0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
```

See it in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fqpdqpe/1/)

Comment: Let's say for example I had a form, upon clicking submit how do I get the value of max in that format. The value should correspond to where the slider is at

Comment: You can do it on submit.  To get the current slider position, use `dateRangeSlider("max")` / `dateRangeSlider("min")`, and then turn it into a JavaScript Date Object to do the formatting.  See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9fqpdqpe/3/).

Comment: Thank you so much, but is there a way to edit the bounds? I'm trying to edit them by following the documentation, but for some reason it is not working correctly

Comment: You may want to use default values, in addition to bounds.   Also keep in mind that in JavaScript months start at `0`.  You may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024392/bounds-are-not-being-set-correctly-jqdaterangeslider/45024816#45024816) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) with methods like [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) (or a library like [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/)):

```
var dateSliderMax = $("#slider").dateRangeSlider("max");
var date = new Date(dateSliderMax.toString());
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
if (month < 10) {
  month = '0'+month;
}
var day = date.getDate();
console.log(''+year+month+day);
```

See it demonstrated in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aelliott/1sz72y30/) or in the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").dateRangeSlider();
  var dateSliderMax = $("#slider").dateRangeSlider("max");
  var date = new Date(dateSliderMax.toString());
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if (month < 10) {
    month = '0' + month;
  }
  var day = date.getDate();
  console.log('' + year + month + day);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderMouseTouch.js"></script>
<script src="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderDraggable.js"></script>
<script src="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderBar.js"></script>
<script src="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderHandle.js"></script>
<script src="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderLabel.js"></script>
<script src="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSlider.js"></script>
<script src="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQDateRangeSliderHandle.js"></script>
<script src="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQDateRangeSlider.js"></script>
<script src="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRuler.js"></script>
<link href="https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/css/iThing.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<article style="padding:50px 20px">

  <div id="slider"></div>

</article>
```

Comment: Let's say for example I had a form, upon clicking submit how do I get the value of max in that format. The value should correspond to where the slider is at

Comment: I see that Chava replied to the same question you posted in a comment on his/her answer. I would recommend that you [ask (i.e. post) a subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of using the comments for that.