# Bounds are not being set correctly jQDateRangeSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui

I am using jQDateRangeSlider for a slider between two dates. I am trying to add two bounds, the minimum bound is where the date can't be less than and the maximum bound is the date where the slider can't be more than. The is in between those two bounds. However, I am having trouble implementing this. It's not being shown correctly. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhegtkb1/)

**HTML**

```
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

**JS**

```
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
  bounds:{
    min: new Date(2011, 05, 31),
    max: new Date(2011, 11, 31)
  }});
```

Comment: notice that options are after bounds:  "bounds",
  {
    min: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2012, 11, 31)  
});

Comment: @AndreiAlexandru Which options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to set the default values.  The bounds will only specify the min and max values for the slider, but these values won't show up as selected.

```
defaultValues: {
    min: new Date(2011, 04, 31),
    max: new Date(2011, 11, 31)
  }
```

If you want the entire slider to be selected, set the bounds and default values to the same dates.

Here's your updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhegtkb1/4/).

Comment: The boundaries are still incorrect though, they don't start at their specified bounds

Comment: Please note that in a JavaScript `Date()`, the months are specified starting at `0` so `new Date(2011, 11, 31)` is actually December 31, 2011, not November.

Comment: Therefore, `new Date(2011, 05, 31)` would be June 31, 11, but since in reality there is no such date, it automatically goes to the next day, which is July, 1, 11.

Answer (score 0):

In [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), months starts with 0 for January to 11 for December.
So if you want the bounds to be from May 30, 2011 to November 30, 2011, it should be:

```
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    bounds:{
    min: new Date(2011, 4, 30),
    max: new Date(2011, 10, 30)
}});
```